# Synchronization issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following scenario in my code (C# .NET 4):

I have a boolean variable that is initialized to false:

```
bool b = false;
```

now I am instantiating number of threads, that each one of them need to read the value of b. the first thread to read b - should change its value to true (and do some logic...), and the others should do nothing. Do I need to use sync mechanism for 'b' while reading its value, or can I lock it only while setting its value to true? 
This should boost my performance, but I am wondering id its safe..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the requirements are:

- multiple threads read a single `bool` variable
- if a thread sees a `false` value it should change it to `true` and perform additional work
- if a thread sees a `true` value then nothing else should happen
- only one thread should be able to change the value and perform the additional work

So the code would look like:

```
public class Example
{
  private bool b = false;

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    if (!b)
    {
      b = true;
      DoExtraStuff();
    }
  }
}
```

This, of course, is not safe if there are multiple threads executing `DoSomething` and the intention is that `DoExtraStuff` should only be executed once. The problem is that the threads will race on the read and write of `b`.

You really need to make the read and write to `b` atomic. This can be done using the `lock` keyword.

```
public class Example
{
  private bool b = false;
  private object locker = new object();

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    bool trigger = false;
    lock (locker)
    {
      if (!b)
      {
        b = true;
        trigger = true;
      }
    }

    if (trigger)
    {
      DoExtraStuff();
    }
  }
}
```

There is an alternate pattern using a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operation via `Interlocked.CompareExhange`. Unfortunately, there is no overload that accepts a `bool`, but if you are willing to change that `bool` to an `int` the following would also work.

```
public class Example
{
  private int b = 0;

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref b, 0, 1) == 0)
    {
      DoExtraStuff();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. More than one thread may see '!b' as true and would enter if-block.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is the correct version. Hopefully the OP comes around and changes the accepted answer so I can delete my answer. I seem to have misunderstood what he wanted to do.

Comment: @Tudor: Yeah, misunderstanding questions happens to me a lot. The wording of this question could have been a little better.